# What is the distribution of this ratio?

Tags: distributions, f-distribution

Suppose $X\sim F(n_1,n_2)$, then, what is the distribution of $Y=\log \frac {\exp(X)}{X}$?

I don't even have a clue about this distribution.

Any helpful suggestions and answers are greatly appreciated!

---

Following Christoph Hanck's suggestion, I got the answer.

Note that $Y=X-\log X \in [1,\inf)$.

The CDF of $Y$ is
$$ 
F(y)=\mathbb{P}(X-\log X \leq y)
$$

Since $f(x)=x-\log x$ monotically increases from $(1,\infty)$ and monotically decreases from $(0,1)$.

Then, we derive the range indicated by $X-\log X \leq y$.

For $$ x-\log x=y $$ we can equivalently obtain $$ -xe^{-x}=-e^{-y} $$

Since $-\frac 1 e\leq-e^{-y}<0$, from the [wiki page w.r.t. the Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), we deduce that there are two roots (as expected).

Finally, we have two roots $$ x_1=W_{-1}(-e^{-y})\\x_2=W_{0}(-e^{-y}) $$

Then,
\begin{align}
F(y)&=\mathbb{P}(W_{-1}(-e^{-y}) \geq X \leq W_{0}(-e^{-y}) )\\
&=\int_{W_{-1}(-e^{-y})}^{W_{0}(-e^{-y})} f_X(x)dx
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
f(y)&=\frac{\partial F(y)}{\partial y}\\
&=f_X\left[ W_{0}(-e^{-y})\right] \frac{\partial W_{0}(-e^{-y})}{\partial y}+f_X\left[ W_{-1}(-e^{-y})\right] \frac{\partial W_{-1}(-e^{-y})}{\partial y}
\end{align}

---

Thanks for the suggestion from @Xi'an.

A more tractable solution can be found from [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function)

Comment: Combining https://www.quora.com/Does-log-a-b-loga-logb and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125573/what-is-a-log-f-distribution could be a starting point

Comment: @Christoph Hanck. Thanks for your suggestion. 
Following your help, I got the solution to this question. 
^_^.

Comment: This is a standard [change of variables in the probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function)

Comment: @Xi'an, thanks, this is a charming and tractable solution to my question.